# How to shorten conditional statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a very long conditional statement like the following:
How to shorten condition statements in Javascript?

```js
var str = document.getElementsByClassName("label");
for(var i = 0; i<str.length; ++i){
if(str[i].innerHTML === "US" || str[i].innerHTML === "VN"|| str[i].innerHTML === "War"...){
str[i].style.display = "none";}}
```

Comment: Don't think this warrants an answer as the question may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but: `if (['US', 'VN', 'War', ...].includes(str[i].innerHTML))`

Answer (score 0):

Use Includes , [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is supported in es6

```
var values = ["US","VN","War"];
if (values.includes(str[i].innerHTML)){

}
```

You can do it with `indexOf(..)>-1` :

```
var values = ["US","VN","War"];
if (values.indexOf(str[i].innerHTML)>-1){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array` with `indexOf` or `includes`.

Note: `includes` will work on ES6 supported browsers

**Working snippet**:

```js
var str = document.getElementsByClassName("label");
var options = ['US', 'VN', 'War'];

for(var i = 0; i<str.length; ++i){
   var text = str[i].innerHTML;
   if(options.indexOf(text) !== -1){
      str[i].style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

```html
<span class="label">US</span>
<span class="label">USA</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing via a regular expression makes it pretty short:

```
if (/^(US|VN|War|etc)$/.test(str[i].innerHTML)) {
```

In context:

```
var str = document.getElementsByClassName("label");
var re = /^(US|VN|War|etc)$/;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    if (re.test(str[i].innerHTML)) {
        str[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

If required you can make it a case-insensitive test by adding the `i` flag to the regex:

```
var re = /^(US|VN|War|etc)$/i;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using jquery by selecting all elements with class `label` then filtering them by checking that their innerHTML is within the array `['US','VN']` and for all that satisfy the filter condition, we change the css style display

```
$(".label").filter(function (){
        return ['US','VN'].includes(this.innerHTML);
   }).css("display","none");
```

Comment: @Jim Yes, thank you.

Comment: @Jim you are right - thanks :) and on thinking about the problem a little bit more I think jquery is better suited as a solution.